# Eigenvalues of a product of matrices with very large elements

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Consider a set of matrices

$M_i = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-b_i}(1+a_i) & a_i \\ a_i & e^{b_i} (1-a_i),
\end{bmatrix}$

where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are of order $O(1)$. (This is an example of the type of matrices I am dealing with, with negative and positive exponentials on the diagonal and determinant $1$).

Consider now their product

$M = \prod_{i=1}^L M_i$ ,

where $L = O(100)$. I am trying to compute

P=$\Im \log \det [I +M]$

**The issue:** If I simply compute $M$ numerically it doesn't behave well, because its elements are exponentially large. For example, both eigenvalues I obtain are exponentially large, so $\det M \neq 1$, which is wrong.

**My approach:** I can obtain P if I compute the eigenvalues of the matrix M. I figured that $\log M$ would be better behave, and I can use it to compute accurately the eigenvalues of M. I know I can compute $\log M$ using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. However, it would be a very messy and unpractical approach.

**My question:** Is there anyway of computing $P$, $\log M$ or the eigenvalues of $M$ directly from the $M_i$ matrices without having to directly compute $M$?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to deal with the numerical instability:

Let $A_i = M_i/\|M_i\|$, where $\|\cdot \|$ denotes the (submultiplicative) matrix norm of your choice (for instance, the Frobenius norm). Let $A = \prod_{i=1}^L A_i$, and let $k = \prod_{i=1}^L \|M_i\|$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\log \det(I + M) &= \log \det \left(\frac{k}{k}(I + M)\right)
\\ & = \log \left[k^2\det(k^{-1}I + A)\right] = 2 \log(k) + \log \det(k^{-1} I + A).
\end{align}
$$
I suspect that it will be possible to compute $A$ directly without significant numerical error.